# Unable to deactivate a closed ( Alpha ) track in Google Play console

Tags: android, google-play

Im a newbie in the Google play console. I have several closed tracks. I am trying to remove a track ( deactivate) but I am unable to. From the instructions that I have seen, you need to open the 'testers' panel and click 'deactivate track'.
However that option is not given to me.
I just want to delete the APK entirely and remove the track. how can I do this ?

[image]

here is the option on the 'Alpha' track.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't completely delete an Alpha version as soon as you released it. Same for Beta versions and productions versions. I got the same problem many times.

For Alpha and Beta versions, the most you can do is to remove affiliated testers so nobody is able to access it anymore but it will stay in the track until you release a new alpha or beta version.

Once you have uploaded your version, you can always find back older testing versions and productions versions in your artefacts. BUT you can't delete an APK which has been uploaded and validated to any track (alpha, beta, prod)

When uploading to Google Play and opening Alpha / Beta tracks, my advice is to perfectly control why you open one, to who and for how long.

I hope it will help you.